# How to allow minus sign in the beginning of number using regex?

Tags: regex

I am not much well versed with the rituals of regex creation. I have these two patterns:

`/[^0-9\.]/g` and `^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$`

I want to modify these two regexs as they start accepting minus sign but only at the start of numerical value.

Comment: add `-?` at the beginning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an optional `-` at the start.

```
^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$
```

`?` (*not next to `+` or `*`*) should turn the previous token as optional one.